# Why this ref-qualified user defined convertion is called?

Tags: c++, c++11

within following small code:

```
class A {    
};

class B {
    public:
    operator A() const & {
        return A{};
    }
};

void foo(const A& a) {

}

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a1 = b;
    A a2 = B{}; //<--- here
    foo(b);
    foo(B{}); //<--- here
}
```

Why the specified lines will not create compile error? My cast operator is lvalue qualified by `&`, so I imagined that it should not be called for these two lines that object is rvalue.

Any idea why this code compiles without any problem? I noticed that if I remove `const` from cast operator declaration, these two lines will make error. But I'm not sure how being const-qualified affect call of this ref-qualified method.

Comment: Are you not familiar with the age old C++ property of const-lvalue references binding to rvalues? That's older than rvalue references and ref-qualifiers

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yea,I know that property. But I thought that calling operator should be decided a step after this binding. That's why I could not get exactly why the operator is called. My mistake anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rvalues could be bound to lvalue-reference to `const` too. (They can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const.)

As the workaround, depending on your intent, you can remove the `const` qualifier as you said, or add overloading with rvalue-reference qualifier (and `const` qualifier if necessary as @HolyBlackCat suggested) and mark it as `delete` explicitly. E.g.

```
class B {
    public:
    operator A() const & {
        return A{};
    }
    operator A() && = delete;
};
```

Comment: Should probably be `operator A() const && = delete;`, otherwise it works with `const` rvalues.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it for the first situation (`A a2 = B{};`) but allow it in 2nd(`foo(B{});`)? I ask this because `B{}` is destroyed after first situation but it is not untill `foo` returns in 2nd example.

Comment: @Afshin I think no. They both perform copy-initialization. And temporaries are destroyed after the full expression, i.e. after the `;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks for info. I thought rather than using cast, it may be better to add an implicit constructor that accepts `const B&` to class `A` and only keep `operator A() && = delete;` in class B. it is funny that the constructor will not be called because of that deleted rvalue cast operator in class B. Do you know reason?

Comment: @Afshin Maybe one is preferred to another in overload resolution; I'm not sure.